# ffmpeg or vlc playlist to rtmp stream?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, vlc, http-live-streaming, m3u8

So, I've read all the articles here and unfortunately I can't seem to find the answers I'm looking for. I've gotten close, but the certain magic strings allude me.

I'm running hls live streaming (nginx) on ubuntu 17.10 server. In short, I can get the server running one video at a time fine with ffmpeg (with subtitles) using the following:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "1.mkv" -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -g 30 -b:v 1000k -s 852x480 -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a 192k -ac 2 -vf subtitles=1.srt -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/show/stream
```

Though, I cannot find a solution to run a playlist using this method. It seems impossible, and when I try vlc via sout (internally, or externally) I reveive either buffer problems, or the aac experimental codec error:

> [aac @ 0xb162e900] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.

Example string that spits that error:

```
vlc "1.mkv" --sout '#transcode{soverlay,vb=1000,vcodec=h264,width=853,height=480,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=rtmp,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=rtmp://localhost:1935/show/stream}'
```

Every other audio codec doesn't work with flv. I'm at a loss, I've tried almost every combination I could think of and digout just to get to this point. The best functioning out of them has been ffmpeg: it doesn't buffer video at all, plays smoothly, but just can't play a playlist. Whereas vlc can play a playlist but buffers, and has no sound (internally). I've tried aenc=ffmpeg{strict=-2}, batch pipes, etc, etc. I need help. Nothing works. Is there any solution? All I want is to run a playlist of 25 videos, all different variations, on a loop to the m3u8 for embedding.

Comment: Upgrade vlc. That `aac` message is from a pre-2016 version of ffmpeg that vlc uses.

Comment: @Gyan That didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine mentioned he used bash scripts to have a seamless playlist like viewing feature. Hopefully that points you in the direction you need. I can try digging them up if you want to work together on this, coz I too am interested in finding out more about it.

Comment: The backdoor solution for this that I came up with using bash scripts was in [the following way](https://pastebin.com/raw/WXH1Hm4M) (I cannot update my original post because of this site's absurd laws).